# How to style the border of a MUI outlined TextField?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Here is my current set up for a TextField component:

```
const styles = {
    resize: {
        fontSize: '50px',
    }
}

const textField = (props) => {

    const { classes } = props;

    return (
        <TextField
            value={props.value}
            placeholder={'$'}
            variant={'outlined'}
            onChange={props.onChange}
            autoFocus
            InputProps={{
                classes: {
                    input: classes.resize
                }
            }}
        />
    );
};

export default withStyles(styles)(textField);
```

When clicking in the text field the border fades away (to a white color). I want the border to stay no matter what and not fade. I tried looking through the material-ui examples for an outlined textfield and came across the "Bare" one which had a fixed border but cannot get it to work in my case. I think I have to dig down through the wrapper components and set the style for the border somewhere? Im not sure.

Answer (score 4):

Taking from my indepth answer https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/13105#issuecomment-427459843 you could add styles to the `notchedOutline` class.

```
<TextField classes={{ notchedOutline: myClassnameWithCustomStyles }} />
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/ppmxn3rp9x

This currently has some limitation which I laid out in the linked comment.

Comment: Any advice on doing this in MUI 5+ with sx props (and no explicit classes)?

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me.

In your style file have this

```
underline: {
  "&:after": {
    borderBottomColor: "rgb(70, 197, 29)",
    borderWidth: "1px"
  }
}
```

And then in my TextField I will implement the abobe within the `InputProp` property

```
          <TextField
              id="standard-number"
              label="Number"
              required
              autoFocus
              classes={{
                root: classes.space,
              }}
              value={some_value}
              onChange={e =>
                this.setState({
                  some_value: e.target.value
                })
              }
              error={some_value === "" || some_value < 0}
              helperText={
                qty_in_mts === ""
                  ? "Please enter Quantity (in M. Tons)"
                  : " "
              }
              label="Quantity (M. Tons)"
              type="number"
              fullWidth
              InputProps={{
                classes: {
                  underline: classes.underline
                }
              }}
            />
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, it works. The problem is that now the click on the text field doesn't open the menu. Do you know why? Thanks x

Comment: I found the answer here, if anyone needs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58791352/material-autocomplete-does-not-work-with-inputprops