# MUI 4 AutoComplete options not visible when set notchedOutline inside InputProps

Tags: material-ui, autocomplete, border-color

In order to set border color to AutoComplete (Material-UI-4) , I am setting notchedOutline as in given code and it works fine but as a side effect it is hiding my Arrow Icon to open dropdown-options and cross icon at right hand side of the AutoComplete.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => {
const isLightTheme = theme.palette.type === 'light';
return {
  root: {
    '& $notchedOutline': {
      borderColor: isLightTheme ? COLORS.GREY : COLORS.WHITE,
    },
  },
  notchedOutline: {},
};
}); 



  <Autocomplete
        id="tech-spaces"
        value={menuItems.find(
          option => option.value === domain.toLowerCase(),
        )}
        options={menuItems}
        getOptionLabel={(option: any) => option.label}
        onChange={onDomainChange}
        renderInput={params => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            label="Domain"
            variant="outlined"
            InputProps={{
              classes: {
                root: classes.root,
                notchedOutline: classes.notchedOutline,
              },
            }}
          />
        )}
        size="small"
      />

[![before][1]][1]




[![After setting notchedOutline][2]][2]


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1fbm.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCGKv.png
```

Answer (score 0):

I hate and glad to say that I got the answer from below post from stackOverflow itself :) .

[Material Autocomplete does not work with InputProps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58791352/material-autocomplete-does-not-work-with-inputprops?rq=2)

Below code change referring above post .

```
InputProps={{
                ...params.InputProps,
                classes: {
                  root: classes.root,
                  notchedOutline: classes.notchedOutline,
                },
              }}
```

Basically I added this part ***...params.InputProps,***